# how to identify a libpng warning in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use a very big number of images in python with  opencv

some of then show a warning of libpng

The images are not mine, I can't use any external program to threat this images.

I just want to now that a image has this warning to discard the image, or at least not to show
the warning to the final user.

I've already try to use warnings.filterwarnings or sys.stderr, but warnings still apears in screen.

Anyone can help me?

A little example:

```
import cv2
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("error")

try:
    cv2.imread('/dados/dev/google/google/downloads/amazan/20.amazan.png')
    print('Image was read')

except Exception as error_e:
    print(f"warning{error_e}")
```

Result :

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 /dados/dev/google/lab/teste.py

libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB

Image was read
```

Comment: These errors are probably coming from the C library, and not anything in the python layer, so using warnings and sys.stderr aren't going to catch it (as you've experienced). 

The only thing that comes to mind at this point is to redirect the STDERR of the process when your script is invoked. Probably not ideal for a script you hope to provide to other users.

Comment: You could try reading in an image as straight binary (not decoding it as PNG) and searching for the string `iCCP` in it. Ignore file if present.

Comment: PNG files are very modular, so you could also edit that chunk out of the file and then load it with OpenCV. Try searching just using `grep` on some files to see if it identifies the troublesome ones and not too many perfectly happy ones correctly.

Comment: Great idea Mark Setchell. Thank you so much. Solved.